# Do we have DataGridview.HitTestType.ColumnResize in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, c#-to-vb.net

we have below functionality for DataGrid

```
DataGrid.HitTestType.ColumnResize
```

so we can capture the column resize activity in MouseDown event as below

```
Dim hti As DataGrid.HitTestInfo = DataGrid1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
If hti.Type = DataGrid.HitTestType.ColumnResize Then
    ......
End if
```

but as I am using DataGridView, where we don't have `DataGridview.HitTestType.ColumnResize`
(as per my knowledge).

Is there any way to acheive same activity as DataGrid in DataGridView?

Comment: @programmer -I am looking for VB.net

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to know whether any columns has been resized then subscribe to `DataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged` event.

[DataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnwidthchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i want to show message to user that "you can not resize column in case of selected row". so i need to capture the activity that user is going to drag the columndivider for resize.
we can do it in case of datagrid as i have mentioned in question above.
but how to do for datagridview as we don't have ColumnResize property for `DataGridview.HitTestType`

Comment: @picnic4u - if you want to prevent resizing you could set the `DataGridViewColumn.Resizable` property to false.

Comment: in my case, if first selected the row and then double clicked on column divider then `ColumnDividerDoubleClick` event is not getting invoke, event is firing after triple click on columndivider.
any idea why? 
without row selection it's firing the `ColumnDividerDoubleClick` event and working as expected.

after selection of row, if dragging the column divider to resize the column it's also not working. so that i want to show one intitutive message to user that in row selection mode, resize option will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to identify which cell is clicked.

To do so you need to register to DataGridView.CellClick event and use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs to understand whiche cell it was. 
An elaborate example can be found on [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: how to identify the column divider mouse drag event for column resize option?